# Move a folder from a repository to another repository

Tags: git, repository

I didn't manage to ask my question properly. 
The situation is : I had a repository on github like this :

OldRepository
- Folder 1
- Folder 2
- Folder 3

And I wanted to move one folder from this repository to another one, like this :

OldRepository
- Folder 1
- Folder 2

NewRepository
- Files and folders from Folder 3

I have followed this tutorial : https://lostechies.com/johnteague/2014/04/04/using-git-subtrees-to-split-a-repository/, but I am stuck at this point "Now that lib folder lives in it’s new repository..."

Currently, my repositories on github are exactly the way I want (the way I show you above). But on my computer the three folders are still in the same folder.

What I have is this :

ProjectFolder
- Folder 1
- Folder 2
- Folder 3

And I want to have is this :

ProjectFolder
- Folder 1
- Folder 2

NewProjectFolder
- Content from folder 3

So what I want is to copy the content of Folder 3 from ProjectFolder to NewProjectFolder, and link this NewProjectFolder to NewRepository.
I don't really get what I need to do, I am very new to git.

Comment: Is the commit history important? Otherwise you can just move it and commit it in the new rep, and rm it from the old one.

Comment: Yes wanted to keep the commit history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As follows, assuming you have only a master branch:

```
cd old_repo
git subtree split -prefix folder3 -branch temp
git rm -r folder3
git commit -m"Removed folder 3 from my old repo"
git checkout temp
cd ..
cp -r old_repo new_repo
cd new_repo
git branch -D master
cd ../old_repo
git checkout master
git branch -D temp
```

Maybe you should leave the `git rm -r` until you're sure you copied the repo properly. Also you may want to rename the branch temp in new_repo to master:

```
cd new_repo
git checkout -B master
git branch -D temp
```

Comment: when i do all the steps everything works, but in the end a lots of files are missing in my Folder 3, is it normal ? I tried three or four times

Comment: The files are in fact at the root of the folder so it's what I wanted. But when I try to push I have `! [rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)`. And it seems to not point to the good repository, I tried to do `git remote set-url origin myurl` but no changes

Comment: The problem was because there was differencies between the local files and the repository on github. I managed it with git pull, everything is ok now, thanks